# Virtual Box Headless Mode: How can I get VRDP server to work with authentication?

Tags: virtualbox

I tried this both on Windows 7 and Snow Leopard (Mac OS X 10.6).

While vrdpauthtype null works (everyone can connect to VMs without user name/password) vrdpauthtype external doesn't work (and RDC connections are just rejected).

Did anyone ever get this to work?

Comment: I'm having the same problem on WinXP.
It seems all the authentication methods are unix only.

Comment: Which version of VBox are you running? And can you confirm that you're connecting to the host (on the set VRDP port) and not trying to RDP to the the guest? What error message do you get when using external authentication?

Comment: I'm running Virtualbox 3.2.4 (The latest version). I am definitely connected to the host, as I can see the Virtualbox POST screen.

When set to any of the other Auth types, the RDP session opens and **immediately** closes, with **no** error message at all on the server.

Comment: To clarify, virtualbox starts without issues when set to External or Guest authentication. However, any RDP session immediately terminates when you connect to the RDP server, with the "Your remote desktop session has ended" Message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've solved the problem.

For some reason, the "External" Authentication method *only* works when you select "Allow me to save credentials" in the RDP initialization window on the *client* end.
Otherwise it fails with the "Your RDP session has Ended" message.

Is there any way to make this work without saving credentials? It's a bit of a security hole.

Comment: Yes, the connection is required to transmit user name and password immediately as there is no system to connect to without authentication. Problem with earlier version of VirtualBox was that auth library was missing for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

In Virtualbox version 4.1 the RDP server requires that you install the [VirtualBox Extension Pack](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html#extpack) before you can connect to a guest using RDP. The settings are there, but without the extension pack the RDP server will not start. You can find additional information in the online user guide under the [VirtualBox RDP Authentication - Null, External, and Guest settings](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#vbox-auth) section.

Comment: I don't think your answer is relevant though. At the time the original question was posted, the extension system didn't even exist and the problem is still there with 4.1 with the extension installed. You still have to save credentials for VRDP to work on MSFT clients...